# Help Me Understand NFS File Sharing Please

Tags: nfs

I really don't understand something with NFS and UID's. When you install Ubuntu you get a default UID of 1000. So if I install Ubuntu on 10 machines, all 10 machines would have a UID of 1000. So when you come to do NFS shares after the users have been on the network for a couple of months, how can you seperate user policies out? If all users are joining a server with UID 1000, there is no way to differentiate between them.

Comment: Yes there is. And it is called `idmapping`

Comment: Yes so I've seen. But it doesn't answer the question. Think about how the mapping would work if 10 users connect with their local UID of 1000. You can't seperate them?

Comment: Hmmm. Easiest fix: change the UUID on 9 of them or store all users on all machines (would basically be the same) and lock 8 of them on each machine (interesting: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/966734 )